# Default values for symfony2 choice radio box

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

My project is written using Silex and Symfony Components (i.e. Form component).

I try to create a battery of radio buttons built from a class and I want to preselect one of those radios.

I create form like that:

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(new QueryFormType(), $query)
```

where `QueryFormType` is my custom type (it extends AbstractType) where I define form fields and `$query` is an entity with default values for the form.

Form fields within `QueryFormType` look like that (I omitted builder and other fields for clarity):

```
->add('contractPeriod', 'filter', array(
  'label' => 'Contract Period:',
  'choices' => array(
    '-1' => 'No period',
    '1' => '1 month',
    '2' => '2 months',
    '3' => '3 months',
    '6' => '6 months',
    '12' => '12 months',
    '18' => '18 months'
  ),
  'expanded' => TRUE,
  'multiple' => FALSE
))
```

`$query` is an instance of a class that should preselect radio button. In it's constructor you will find:

```
$this->contractPeriod = '3';
```

It has correct getters and setters for this property too.

Now. The form and radio buttons are rendered properly. Radio button is preselected to `'3' => '3 months'`. When I check radio higher in the definition list (so 2, 1 or -1) form accepts it as a value. But when I check value lower in the defined list (6, 12 or 18) it uses default value set in `$query`. What the heck?

My question is how to set default value correctly so I can pick whatever other value I want after the form is rendered?

I already tried using 'data' property in the form field definition and it is the same story. I can select only lower values but no higher. I tired to use 'preferred_choices' but it does not work the way I would expect (messed up IDs of the inputs).

I beg you for help.

EDIT

This is how I submit the form:

```
$form->submit($request->query->get($form->getName()), FALSE);
```

I found out that if I set clearMissing to TRUE (second argument) it works well but I cannot do partial prefilling (or patch the form). Seem to be a bug.

EDIT

It has something to do with those lines inside Form class of symfony components:

```
if ($isSubmitted || $clearMissing) {
    $child->submit($isSubmitted ? $submittedData[$name] : null, $clearMissing);
    unset($submittedData[$name]);

    if (null !== $this->clickedButton) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($child instanceof ClickableInterface && $child->isClicked()) {
        $this->clickedButton = $child;

        continue;
    }

    if (method_exists($child, 'getClickedButton') && null !== $child->getClickedButton()) {
        $this->clickedButton = $child->getClickedButton();
    }
}
```

$child->submit updates viewData of its parent (Form in this case) to submited value only if it's lower/equal to default value set in the form. Why?

EDIT

I think that Form component wont submit children after default value that in that case isSubmited == false and clearMissing == false. That makes only values up to default value available. But I don't know.

Comment: You tried using `data`? `'data' => '1',`, for example. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html#data

Comment: Yes I did. I already wrote it in the question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sorry, what about `empty_data`?

Comment: It is something in the core of Form component. It is how it handles radio colletion. Empty_data has different purpose.

Comment: It's odd, because I recently tested this, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Try creating a form with get method and choice field with 5 options, expanded and not multiple. Set default value in the middle i.e. 3. Then submit form with flag set to FALSE (clearMissing) and try picking something above 3 (4, 5). Or try prefilling it using URL.