# Symfony2 - render an array collection within an entity as radio not as (dropdown) chioce field

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button, twig

I created a form with an collection of forms - the user shall be able to edit many items within one screen. 
Each entity in the collection of forms consists for example of a text field and a choice field. The choice field contains some text options (of course).

I know that there is an option like here [ [Default values for symfony2 choice radio box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524795/default-values-for-symfony2-choice-radio-box) ] to define the possible values within the form type by giving an array.

But I do not want to iterate over my array collection within the form builder when I can avoid that. Because the collection is not just an array of strings but it is a collection of an entity (with a __toString() function so that I can get a textual representation for each of it).

Is there a way to render a radio field instead of the default dropdown choice field within the twig teamplate? Or by giving a special option to the form builder (without a loop)?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display a `entity` field using radios instead of select, you just have to set the `expanded` attribute to true:

```
$builder->add('post', 'entity', ['expanded' => true]);
```

If you also add the `multiple` attribute, you have a set of checkboxes instead.

[Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons)

Comment: True. I'll post my slightly more complex example the next days. Thanks for giving the hint!